# Latexmk with makeindex and -output-directory

Tags: latexmk, nomenclature

My current `.latexmkrc` looks (more or less) like this:

```perl
$pdflatex = "xelatex -src-specials -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S";

# for nomenclature
add_cus_dep("nlo", "nls", 0, "nlo2nls");
sub nlo2nls {
    system("makeindex $_[0].nlo -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].nls -t $_[0].nlg");
}
```

`makeindex` works as expected. Being a lazy person I'd like to use that shiny new feature of `latexmk` and output to a build directory to reduce clutter (`$out_dir`). Unfortunately I did not find a way to tell `latexmk` to look in that directory for the `.nlo` dependency (I guess it looks in the source files' dir).

Any ideas how to modify `nlo2nls`?

Comment: Did you try adding `$out_dir/` in front of each `$_[0]`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that doesn't work. The problem seems to be that latexmk doesn't find the dependency file: `Latexmk: Missing input file: 'thesis.nls'`. This is expected, as `thesis.nls` is generated from `thesis.nlo` which is is output to `build/`.

Comment: It works for me with version 4.30a with exactly the custom dependency you defined.  If you don't have the current version of `latexmk`, I would upgrade, since there were some problems with building to an output directory in earlier versions.  If you have the problem with the current version, I would need to see more details to debug the problem.